# how to access array element within touchEnded in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, touchesbegan

I am having a very strange behaviour about the TouchesEnded Method

I am using this syntax to access the array element

```
int cal=((b * (b-a-1))+4);
printf("cal is %d",cal);
c=[file_contents objectAtIndex:cal];          
printf("message2------%d",c);
```

and its working fine anywhere in the program but when i called this above piece of code in 
`touchesEnded` function its crashing the app>>

Actually this is my function that i am calling two times one in the `viewdidload` and again in the `touchesEnded`

```
int values_retrieval(int a,int b)
{
//NSLog(@"for loop variable i=%i--> the retrieve coordinates are::%@", a,[file_contents objectAtIndex:(b * (b-a-1))+4]);
printf("message111111111");
int cal=((b * (b-a-1))+4);
printf("cal is %d",cal);
NSString *c=[file_contents objectAtIndex:cal];
int val=[c intValue];
printf("message222222222------%d",val);
return val;
}
```

when it is called in `viewdidload` all is going well and when it is called in `touchesEnded` method the app crashed

I have no idea what is going wrong

here is my TouchedEnded method

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint     touchedEnd;

    int index=5;
    int i=3;
    printf("value of i is %d",i);
    NSString *test=values_retrieval(i, index);
    printf("val issssssssssssssssssss %d",test);

    touchedEnd = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:touch.view];
}
```

Any idea or help is appreciated

Comment: show the complete code

Comment: and error text would be helpful

Comment: Put touchesEnded code

Comment: @AKV  i edit m the question and added the code

Comment: @JohnPoison i edited my question view the code for better understanding

Comment: @Vinu1991 Question is edited with code as well take a look>>

Comment: i cant see any error here, you must be getting error from some other place like touchesEnded( ). Also show touchesEnded method.

Comment: @AKV i have put the code for Method TouchesEnded its not working just a simple code>>

Comment: now i can see you are calling methods `NSString *test=values_retrieval(i, index);` and `    touchedEnd = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:touch.view];` And i guess the error is coming from there. Use breakpoint to reach to exact source of error.

Comment: NSString *c=[file_contents objectAtIndex:cal];


this is the line where i am getting error of 
EXC_BAD_ACESS

any help @AKV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your comment :

> NSString *c=[file_contents objectAtIndex:cal]; this is the line where
>   i am getting error of EXC_BAD_ACESS any help @AKV

The error `EXC_BAD_ACESS` is shown when you do not retain the object and it is released and tries to access it.

If you are using ARC, make sure `file_contents` is of `strong` type.

If you are using non-ARC, use `retain`.

Comment: same error that you mention>> retain matters

thaks for your help

Comment: both the answer are correct>> so just one is the more abstract>> and today i completely understand>> its your accepted now 
. thanks

Answer (score 1):

c is being treated an int and you're assigning an object to it in printf().

Chances are cal is outside of the bounds of the array, or your array went out of Scope and no longer exists because you're using ARC, or you released it otherwise.

Try this:

```
int cal=((b * (b-a-1))+4);
printf("cal is %d",cal);
if(cal > file_contents.count-1) 
{
printf("Cal is too big"); 
}
else 
{
c=[file_contents objectAtIndex:cal];    
}      
NSLog(@"message2------%@", c);
```

Comment: @Stephan this is not the error because my cal value is always less than the array index , i have checked it

Comment: Ok, I address 3 separate possibilities. Make sure your memory is not released. We'll need the full code for this one if that doesn't fix anything. Thanks for posting little bits at a time so far though!

Comment: Alright, well it looks like I did answer your question with this: "and no longer exists because you're using ARC, or you released it otherwise."